# How can I measure complex I/O activity to develop realistic benchmarking?

Tags: linux, storage, io, benchmark, ceph

I need to retrieve a few metric from my service server to benchmark another stroage solution. There are various options are provied by benchmark program(I choosed FIO,http://freecode.com/projects/fio). I could easily set up io pattern with it. But I couldn’t know how can i retrive real service’s metric to set up benchmark varible as realistic as possible.

for exmaple, i need to setup,

- random/sequential read/write ratio file size and distribution of each
- file size (if i could possible, random/sequential read/write ratio for each size)
- iodepth
- random access’s revisitaion ratio(might affect random access performance)

I’m currently testing ceph(http://ceph.com/), At least above metrics seems significant impact for those kind of storage from my study. How can i retrieve those value?

collectcl(http://collectl.sourceforge.net/) seemed promssing. But couldn’t figure out any further than read/write ratio. I couldn’f figure out except those thing. I really like to know how other people decide those benchmark variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not really understand the question... what do you need excatly?

Comment: @MichelZ for exmaple, i can't decide file size to benchmark. There might be prominent file size in real use case. So How can i get statistic or data which can decide benchmark file size from my currently serving server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [blktrace](http://linux.die.net/man/8/blktrace) to record real system storage activity and profile an existing workload. That can be captured to file.

The trace can then be [replayed](http://linux.die.net/man/8/btreplay).

Another interesting possibility *could* be the use of the new [sysdig utility](http://www.sysdig.org) to try to analyze what's going on under representative workloads.

In addition, an answer here shows an interesting approach using [System Tap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/):
 [Linux utility to record IO statistics (random/sequential, block sizes, read/write ratio)](https://serverfault.com/questions/425821/linux-utility-to-record-io-statistics-random-sequential-block-sizes-read-writ/537734#537734)

Comment: +1 for replaying traces. That's how we benchmark high intensity oracle work on multi-tier pools.